# html2canvas: Creating a browser extension that takes a screenshot of the HTML body

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, html2canvas, webpage-screenshot

I'm creating a basic browser extension that converts the current HTML body to an image that can be downloaded via html2canvas. The problem is that the extension only saves an image of the extension popup window, and not the webpage.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Screenshot</h2>
    <input type="button" id="screenshot" value="Screenshot Body"/>
    <script src="screenshot.js"></script>
    <script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
const screenshotEl = document.getElementById("screenshot")

screenshotEl.addEventListener("click", takeScreenshot);

function takeScreenshot() {
    html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
        chrome.downloads.download({
        url: dataURL,
        filename: "screenshot.png",
        saveAs: true
      });
    });
}
```

Any idea on how I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You have to use a service worker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `html2canvas` runs in the scope of the extension popup, but you want it to be running in the user's browser DOM scope. You can do that by [sending a message](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/) from the popup JS file to a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/). The content script will run in the DOM context and take the photo you need.

In the popup JS file, you will send a message like this:

```js
(async () => {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true});
  const response = await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {action: "screenshot"});
  console.log(response); // the content script responds with the data or a success message
})();
```

Then wait for the message in the content script:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action === "screenshot") {
      html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
        chrome.downloads.download({
          url: dataURL,
          filename: "screenshot.png",
          saveAs: true
        });
      });
      sendResponse({message: "success"});
    }
  }
);
```

Be sure to also import the `html2canvas.js` source in the content script context instead of the popup context as well.

Comment: I know this is old, But I am having trouble importing external scripts. How do you import html2canvas into the content.js file?